# ng-click on div tag won't execute

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I want to change my CSS on a div when it has been clicked on, but I can't seem to get it to work. Here's the div itself:

```
<div class="info-box" ng-class="{'info-box-active':isActive}" ng-click="activeBtn">
<div class="box-row">
    <div class="header">
        <p class="leftText">IKANO Bostad</p>
        <p class="rightText">Leveransrum</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="box-row">
    <div class="fields">
        <p class="leftText">Folkungagatan 100</p>
        <p class="rightText">10 kr/månad</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's the JS:

```
$scope.isActive = false
$scope.activeBtn = function () {
    $scope.isActive = !$scope.isActive
}
```

I bet it's a super basic and dumb problem, but I've been sitting with this for a while now..

Comment: You have to call the function inside `ng-click`, so it should be `ng-click="activeBtn()"`.

Comment: Thanks for replying so quickly @KarlenKishmiryan. But it doesn't work with the `()`.

Comment: Have you created the `controller` correctly?

Comment: @KarlenKishmiryan I added some more info below! Maybe it will help you to solve my problem! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Typo Mistake:

```
   ng-click="activeBtn"  should be  ng-click="activeBtn()" 

<div class="info-box" ng-class="{'info-box-active':isActive}" ng-click="activeBtn()">
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/11955/

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! But that doesn't seem to do the trick :/

Comment: Is this still calling the method?

Comment: I added some more info!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="info-box" 
ng-class="{'info-box-active':isActive}" 
ng-click="isActive=!isActive">
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.